# Why a recursive function changes its argument in an expected way (C++)?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am writing a recursive pre-order traversal for a following binary tree:
[enter image description here][1].

The binary tree is set as `line = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,null,8,9,10,11,null,12,13]";` in `int main()`.

I wrote my solution in the function:

```
class Solution {
private:
    void traverse(TreeNode* root, vector<int> answer){
        if (root == NULL){
            return;
        }
        answer.push_back(root->val);
        traverse(root->left,answer);
        traverse(root->right,answer);
    }
public:
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root){  //function preorderTraversal() output type is vector<int>
        vector<int> answer;
        answer.clear();
        traverse(root,answer);
        return answer;
    }
};
```

The variable `root` is the binary tree set by variable `line`.

The variable `answer` is the returned value of pre-order traversal.

Both of them are the input arguments of the recursive function `void traverse(TreeNode* root, vector<int> answer)`.

The recursive function `traverse` is set as a private member function.

I am expecting the result to be:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 9, 10, 3, 6, 11, 7, 12, 13]
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

However, when I ran this code with Xcode, I got the following output:

```
[]
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I found that the values in `answer` will be deleted when my traversal nodes move back to their roots!

I can only make it work by removing the variable `answer` as an argument for the recursive function and set it as a public variable like this:

```
class Solution {
private:
    void traverse(TreeNode* root){
        if (root == NULL){
            return;
        }
        answer.push_back(root->val);
        traverse(root->left);
        traverse(root->right);
    }
public:
    vector<int> answer;
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root){  //function preorderTraversal() output type is vector<int>
        answer.clear();
        traverse(root);
        return answer;
    }
};
```

My question is: why recursive function `traverse` would not **keep the results** assigned to `answer` when I use this variable as an argument?

Thank you!

The complete code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct TreeNode
{
    // member vars
    int val;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
    // constructor
    TreeNode(int x): val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {} //Initialize val=x, left=NULL, right=NULL, x is the value of root
};

class Solution {
private:
    void traverse(TreeNode* root, vector<int> answer){
        if (root == NULL){
            return;
        }
        answer.push_back(root->val);
        traverse(root->left,answer);
        traverse(root->right,answer);
    }
public:
    //vector<int> answer;
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root){  //function preorderTraversal() output type is vector<int>
        vector<int> answer;
        answer.clear();
        traverse(root,answer);
        return answer;
    }
};
void trimLeftTrailingSpaces(string &input) {
    input.erase(input.begin(), find_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](int ch) {
        return !isspace(ch);
    }));
}

void trimRightTrailingSpaces(string &input) {
    input.erase(find_if(input.rbegin(), input.rend(), [](int ch) {
        return !isspace(ch);
    }).base(), input.end());
}

TreeNode* stringToTreeNode(string input) {
    trimLeftTrailingSpaces(input);
    trimRightTrailingSpaces(input);
    input = input.substr(1, input.length() - 2);
    if (!input.size()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    string item;
    stringstream ss;
    ss.str(input);

    getline(ss, item, ',');
    TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(stoi(item));
    queue<TreeNode*> nodeQueue;
    nodeQueue.push(root);

    while (true) {
        TreeNode* node = nodeQueue.front();
        nodeQueue.pop();

        if (!getline(ss, item, ',')) {
            break;
        }

        trimLeftTrailingSpaces(item);
        if (item != "null") {
            int leftNumber = stoi(item);
            node->left = new TreeNode(leftNumber);
            nodeQueue.push(node->left);
        }

        if (!getline(ss, item, ',')) {
            break;
        }

        trimLeftTrailingSpaces(item);
        if (item != "null") {
            int rightNumber = stoi(item);
            node->right = new TreeNode(rightNumber);
            nodeQueue.push(node->right);
        }
    }
    return root;
}

string integerVectorToString(vector<int> list, int length = -1) {
    if (length == -1) {
        length = list.size();
    }

    if (length == 0) {
        return "[]";
    }

    string result;
    for(int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        int number = list[index];
        result += to_string(number) + ", ";
    }
    return "[" + result.substr(0, result.length() - 2) + "]";
}

int main() {
    string line;
    //while (getline(cin, line)) {
        line = "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,null,8,9,10,11,null,12,13]";
        TreeNode* root = stringToTreeNode(line);

        vector<int> ret = Solution().preorderTraversal(root);

        string out = integerVectorToString(ret);
        cout << out << endl;
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between passing parameters by value versus by reference? If you do, look at your program carefully. If you don't, open your C++ book, and read the explanation. If you have a Java background, and think that objects work the same way in C++ as they do in Java, then that's the mistake here: C++ is not Java, so you need to review everything your C++ book says about C++, from the start.

Comment: It appears (because you are clearing the 'answer' prior to use) that the function 'traverse' parameter 'answer' should be a reference. Because  the function is filling the 'answer' vector, try changing the signature to "... vector<int>& answer)"

Comment: I found this quickly by adding cout's at useful points (my second guess isolated the issue).  But If that is not the only issue, you really ought to try out your debugger ... a valuable skill to have.

Comment: Thank you! The code works when I change to ...class Solution {
private:
    void traverse(TreeNode* root, vector<int>& answer){
        if (root == NULL){
            return;
        }
        answer.push_back(root->val);
        traverse(root->left,answer);
        traverse(root->right,answer);
    }
public:
    vector<int> preorderTraversal(TreeNode* root){  //function preorderTraversal() output type is vector<int>
        vector<int> answer;
        answer.clear();
        traverse(root,answer);
        return answer;
    }
};...